# Parse a HTML page and assign <b>value</b> to a PHP variable on button click

Tags: javascript, php, html, parsing

I am working on a QR scanner and using webqr Javascript QR code reader to decode the QR image. It works fine and I am able to retrieve the decoded text. I am also using a "simple_html_dom.php" to parse the page. Initially the `<div id="result></div>` is empty but once the image is uploaded new tags appear:

```
<div id="result" style="display:none;">
#This appears after an image is uploaded containing the decoded text:
**<br>
<b>text</b>
<br>**
<br></div>
```

Therefore I cannot start parsing the page before the image is uploaded and I am starting that only after the button is clicked after user uploaded the image.

My idea is that once the button is clicked the parsing process starts, retrieves the decoded text from `<b>text</b>` tags and assigns it to the variable. Also, it sends that variable in the URL so that the another page can retrieve it and do the query. Essentially that decoded text should be an item ID.

```
<?php       
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        $html = file_get_html('http://example.com/Inventory/scanner1.php');
        $match = $html->find('p', -1);
        $link = "http://example.com/Inventory/scanner_result.php?id=" . $match;
        echo "<script language='text/javascript'>";
             . "window.location.href='$link'"
             . "</script>";
    }
?>
```

Below I have some html and here is the tag that I was testing:

```
<p>AAA</p>
```

It works when I only open the page. Parsing works and I can also pass it to another page just fine. However, it seems that when I upload the image I cannot see/parse a new  tag that appeared. Please let me know if my approach is correct and what can I do to solve it. Thanks!!!

Comment: have you tried AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your button to parse the content after load only fires the javascript rather than submitting a form (requiring a page reload) and then checking the post settings?

Comment: only fires the javascript rather than submitting a form? Not sure what you mean....it does fire up the javascript and redirects to a different page. It also parses the steady (I would say) html. However, it doesn't see/parse the newly appeared html block consisting of <b> tags below <div> result.